# How do I find a spanning tree of a graph using a breadth first search?

Tags: matrices

For a practice question I have been given I have been told to find a spanning tree using a breadth first search for the following graph:

[image]

From this point onwards I know only to construct an adjacency matrix and that is all. How would I go about doing a breadth first search? Also, how would I choose the initial nodes to begin the search?

Answer (score 3):

First, you should choose an arbitrary vertex, let it be $1$ to make it simple.

Then, the algorithm starts, $1$ is "done", now we check all neighbours of $1$, and we write them to our list: $1,2,3$. (We made the edges (1,2) and (1,3)).
No more neighbours, so we check for new ones. $2$ has no more neighbours, $3$ has $4$ as a neighbour, so we have $1,2,3,4$(We made edge (3,4)).
After this, we have $1,2,3,4,5,6$(We made edge(4,5)(4,6)).
If you start the algorithm with $1$, then this is your result.

Your spanning tree: Vertexes are $1,2,3,4,5,6$, edges are $(1,2),(1,3), (3,4), (4,5),(4,6)$.

My description was not very "professional", but hope you understand the task. :)

Here is an other example to make it clearer, from Wikipedia:

[image]

We want to make a spanning tree from Frankfurt. This is the result if you run BFS:

[image]

Comment: Can you think of a reason why in my lecturer's solution he started at node 3 so all of his edges are (3,1), (3,2) for example. What's the criteria for choosing a starting node in the matrix?

Comment: It is arbitrary, where you start. The starting edge doesn't matter, only the method.

Comment: If you start at node $3$, your edges will be(3,1)(3,2)(3,4), and after this, you use node $4$ to get (4,5)(4,6), that will be your spanning tree.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use any searching method on a connected graph to generate a spanning tree, with any source vertex.

Consider connecting a vertex to the "parent" vertex that "found" this vertex. Then, since every vertex is visited eventually, there is a path leading back to the source vertex.

By picking $2$ vertices $a, b$ and their paths to the source vertex, we see that there is a path between $a$ and $b$. Hence the graph is connected. Every vertex other than the source vertex generates an edge, so this graph has $n-1$ nodes. As such, it is a spanning tree of the original graph.